# Adjusting Nelder-Mead

Tags: algorithm, optimization, parameters, simplex

Is there a way to adjust the α (reflection), β (expansion), γ (contraction), or δ (shrink) parameters in Nelder-Mead optimization to account for overdispersed data distribution?

I've tried setting α as 1 or 2, and β as 0.5, 2, or 4, but still without luck reaching convergence.